# Parse Trees - Arithmetic Expressions

Tags: arithmetic, trees

In regards to the **right side** of this expression (c * (a-b)) how is it factored to include (-) instead of * and then (-) again?

[image]

I cant understand what steps my teacher made to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The tree is wrong; your instructor screwed up.  The tree shown there is for $(3\cdot a+5\cdot(b+a))/(c-(a-(b\cdot c)))$.  Also, it is not a parse tree, but an abstract syntax tree.